# VB Script to change desktop wallpaper on startup

Tags: powershell, vbscript, console, wallpaper

Due to some mardy users voting down my last one, I'll change the question.

I want to create a VBScript, or whatever method you deem possible to do so. That sets the desktop background to a desired image on PC startup.

Anybody shed light on how to do so
Would running a powershell script be better suited to do so or?

I work mainly with C# and .NET technologies, so this is kind of out my area

Comment: I made a HTA with vbscript to change the wallpaper tested only on windows 7.
So if you like to test it; I will share this code as answer ! and you should also add the tag HTA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the best option. But you could edit the registry entry that is responsible for your background and update the necessary parameter.

Save the following in a bat file and put it into auto-start.

```
@echo off
reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "" /f 
reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\[LOCATION OF WALLPAPER HERE]" /f 
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperStyle /f
reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /t REG_SZ /d 2 /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 
exit
```

All Credits to [Tim](https://superuser.com/questions/277805/how-do-i-set-the-desktop-background-on-windows-from-a-script)

Kind Regards
spitterfly

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it through Powershell you could follow the instructions [Here](http://www.theagreeablecow.com/2014/09/set-desktop-wallpaper-using-powershell.html)

The meat of it is you can preform this task by a simple command

```
Set-Wallpaper [Source] [Selection]
```

Now this can be achieved by pre-loading the Set-Walpaper.ps1 that was written by "TheAgreeableCow" and the code can be found on [GITHUB](https://gist.github.com/theagreeablecow/580797ac061698a6e0af#file-set-wallpaper-ps1)

Comment: spitterfly gave me the answer I needed, but I tried this also and it works, so thank you